# How to change edit text after view created

Tags: android, textview

I need to change the text of a EditText and a TextView with the return of an activity.

So, in the onActivityResult I did the following:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    EditText edit = (EditText)findViewByID(R.id.edit);
    edit.setText(extras.GetString("edit");
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(extras.GetString("tv");
}
```

The text of the TextView is changed, but the text of the EditText isn't.

If I change the text on the onCreate everything works, but on the onActivityResult just the TextView works.

My question is: how can I change the text of the EditText on the onActivityResult?

Comment: `extras.getString("edit")` is returning the text you want in `onActivityResult`?

Comment: Hmm..you sure the call to extras.GetString("edit") is not returning empty? Does your edittext have anything in it before you try to change it?

Comment: Udlse getstringextra instead of getstring

Comment: set the same varible!

Comment: @KenWolf yes, I already tried to change to a static String.

Comment: @JadeByfield the getString is returning a text, I already tried to change to a static String. My editText has text, I need to empty the edit text before setting the new text? I don't have any type of listener in the EditText.

Comment: The code posted above shouldn't compile. It's missing closing brackets  on some lines and there is no GetString() with a capital G...Post the actual code.

Comment: @jonathanrz, could you try to add `edit.invalidate();` at the end of your code?

Comment: @KenWolf the place where I work don't allow me to post the code, I wrote that code just for the question. Sorry.

Comment: @jonathanrz well, other than not compiling, what you posted looks fine and the EditText text should change. :-)

Comment: @KenWolf I believe that my problem is elsewhere, thanks.

Comment: I ran into the similar problem. Debugging it, I could see that the EditText is indeed there and manipulable (edit.setText("hello") actually updates edit), but the view is not updated. I am using it in a fragment, and none of the suggested solutions worked for me. Still investigating.

Comment: My mistake was that onActivityResult() is called before onResume(). Make sure you do not implement onResume() and fill your EditText there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see below a working simple example of how you can change the text of an `EditText` in the method `onActivityResult`.

Here is the code for the first activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Bundle result = data.getExtras();
        if (!result.isEmpty() && result.containsKey("data")) {
            final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            editText.setText(data.getStringExtra("data"));
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the code of the second activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent result = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    result.putExtra("data", "test");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();

}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution, but that code proves that my problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct, but Android has its pitfalls and landmines (as usual!)

You can force a EditText.SetText("blablabla..."); inside your OnActivity Result 
in 3 EASY steps:

1. Reload your layout into your Activity
2. Rebind your EditText
3. use SetText as usual.

In this sample code, I pass a URL string with and intent and write it into a TextView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{       
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        QRdata= data.getStringExtra("QRURL"); //Get the String from the Intent

        if (QRdata.length()>0)//Continue if the Intent´s text is not empty..
        {

                            //Step1
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmpackage); 
                            //Step2
            TextView qrtxt=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.qrurl); 
                            //Setp 3,Voilà!
            qrtxt.setText(QRdata.toString()); 

        }
```

Comment: Reinflate the view in the onActivityResult is slow :/.

Comment: It's up to the programmer's criteria to decide, but quite too often, it's cheaper to go through the short path instead of going into more complex code just to do a simple task like modifying an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change your views in the OnActivityResult - as that's a sure way to get your program crashed if the activity was stopped and was at some point wiped off the memory - and now is being recreated.

In this case, onActivityResult will highly likely run before the views finish to inflate from the OnCreate - setContentView method.

---

Do not use setContentView in the onActivityResult either, because it will duplicate the expensive operation which was performed in the OnCreate method.

---

The workaround (when you use the data from OnActivityResult for filling the UI views, such as EditText or TextView) is to set up a variable that would keep the value from the extras and then use this variable later - specifically in the OnResume method.